# Is there a way to play sequence music notes by one next step when clicking a button in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, audio-player

I'm making an app that can load a midi file or a mml(music macro language) string to play music.

I found that SiON can easily do that. (https://sites.google.com/site/sioncenter/)

My problem is I want to write a feature that User can pause sequence. Then touch a button to play sequence step by step.

Do you have any suggest for me with SiON or whatever as3 framework?

The ipad app "Baby Loves Salsa" do the exactly what I want to do if you want a reference.

Comment: I found `SoundObject.stop()` and `SoundObject.play()` in the [API](http://www.libspark.org/htdocs/as3/sion/org/si/sound/SoundObject.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

SoundObject.play() is continue playing the sequence. What I'm trying to do is pause the sequence then play step by step whenever I call method SoundObject.playNextNote() for example.